# Sorting dgrid column does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, sorting, dojo, dgrid, dijit.layout

I have a dgrid table comprising 13 columns.

The sort in decreasing order works as expected: Highest values, followed by lowest values, followed by entries that have no values.

However, when I sort in ascending order, there are fields with no values, then fields with 0, then fields with no values again and finally fields with values in ascending order.

I have looked into source code, but I am unable to figure out what is causing this.

Is this a bug with dgrid sorting?

What could be the workaround for this?

Comment: Provide an example of the data you are sorting. Are you sure the fields are truly empty and that they are not populated with invisible characters like " " or "\t" or similar?

Comment: can you create a sample or jsfiddle where we can reproduce the same issue....

Comment: Hi, looks like since the column fields are a combination of empty strings, zeros and non-zero numbers, sorting does not work as expected. How can i sort by empty fields first, followed by zero's and other numbers in ascending order and vice versa in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your column is read-only, you could add a field in the data source (see `displayValue` in the code below) reflecting your values, but where **strings are replaced with a negative number**.

Then, instead of the real field, put only this field in the grid. And display the real value in the `get` function of the column.

I've used the same workaround to apply a case-insensitive sort in a column populated with proper names.

```js
require(["dgrid/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Grid) {

 var data = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) for(j = 1; j <= 2; j++) data.push({value: i});
 for(i = 1; i < 3; i++) data.push({value: ""});

 data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.displayValue = typeof item.value == "string" ? -1 : item.value;
 });

 var grid = new Grid({
  columns: {
   displayValue: {
    label: "Value",
    get: function(item) { return item.value; }
   }
  }
 }, 'grid');

 grid.renderArray(data);
 grid.set("sort", "displayValue");
  
});
```

```html
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    packages: [
      {
        name: 'dgrid',
        location: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0'
      }
    ]
  }
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/dgrid.css"/>
  
<style>
  .dgrid-row-table {
      height: 24px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="grid" style="width:200px;height:210px">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The solutions looks good, but does it handle if the column is combination of strings. How does it handle comparison of -1 with "foo". We need a custom sort function in this case?

Comment: In this case the test in the forEach should be changed to: `item.displayValue = (!item.value && typeof item.value == "string") ? -1 : item.value;`. However, I've tried to mix numbers and strings in the grid (without my workaround), and anyway the sort does not work properly in this case: first sort in ascending order => strings are before numbers, next sort in ascending order => numbers are before strings (!). AFAIK, we can't use a custom sort function with dgrid. Here is an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197919/dgrid-custom-sort-issue.

Comment: I was thinking of custom sort because, all the columns i have in spreadsheet are of mixed types. There is a column with string with numbers "g1", "g23", "g19" , "", "g13". But dgrid sort does not work in the desired way on this. How can i handle this optimally without having to write own custom sort function?.  As of now i tried listening to 'dgrid-sort' event and set a  custom sort function ( this.spreadsheetGrid.dgridTable.set("sort", function(obj1, obj2) {}); depending on the column i would like to sort.

Comment: See my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

**= Better answer as my last post, after your comments =**

AFAIK, dgrid (and also dstore) doesn't allow to use a custom sort function.

The pattern below overcomes this limitation. It uses an `OnDemandGrid` populated with a `dstore`.

For instance, the `field1` column of this grid contains values ranging from "g1" to "g20". They are not sorted aphanumerically (default sort) but numerically (**custom sort** based on the numbers after "g") => "g1" < "g2" < "g3" < ... < "g10" < "g11"...

This custom sort is performed by the `comparegXX` callback function:

```
var comparegXX = function(a, b) {
  // 'compare' is a generic comparison function for values of the same type
  try {
    return compare(parseInt(a.value.substr(1), 10), parseInt(b.value.substr(1), 10));
  }
  catch(ex) { return compareMixedTypes(a, b); }
}
```

... and `comparegXX` is assigned to `field1` in its column definition (`sort` attribute):

```
field1: {
    sort: comparegXX
},
```

It' the same for `field2` (mixed types sort - strings and numbers - performed by `compareMixedTypes`).

If you want to assign another custom sort to a field, write your custom comparison callback function and add it in the column definition of the field: `fieldX: {sort: myCompareFunction}`.

Note that the store shouldn't contain any field named `_newPos`. This field is created and used by the `doSort` function. It contains the new relative positions of the data rows after applying the custom sort - the new sort of the grid is based on this field.

```js
var compare = function(a, b) { return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0; }

// comparison functions for custom sorts
// use a.value and b.value in these functions, not directly a and b

var comparegXX = function(a, b) {
  try {
    return compare(parseInt(a.value.substr(1), 10), parseInt(b.value.substr(1), 10));
  }
  catch(ex) { return compareMixedTypes(a, b); }
}

var compareMixedTypes = function(a, b) {
  var aType = typeof a.value;
  return aType == typeof b.value ? compare(a.value, b.value) :
    aType == "string" ? -1 : 1;
}

require(["dstore/Memory", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dojo/domReady!"], function (Memory, OnDemandGrid) {

  // populate the store (random values in field2)

  var tbl = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
    var item = {id: i};
    item.field1 = "g" + i;
    item.field2 = (i == 1 || Math.random() < 0.2) ? "" : Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    tbl.push(item);
  }
 
  var store = new Memory( {data: tbl });

  var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
    collection: store,
    columns:
    {
      id: {},
      field1: {
        sort: comparegXX
      },
      field2: {
        sort: compareMixedTypes
      }
    },
  }, 'grid');
 
  var lastField = null;
  var descending = null;

  grid.doSort = function(e) {
  
    // custom sort of the grid, replaces the default sort
    
    var field = e.sort[0].property;

    if(lastField == field) descending = !descending;
    else {
      lastField = field;
      if(descending == null) descending = e.sort[0].descending;
    }

    var sortFunc = grid.column(field).sort;
  
    if(sortFunc) {
      // calculate the positions of the rows based on the custom compare function,
      // they are stored in the _newPos field, and then the grid is sorted on it
      var tmp = [], tmp2 = {};
      store.forEach(function(item, i) { tmp.push({value: item[field], pos: i}); });
      tmp.sort(sortFunc);
      tmp.forEach(function(item, i) { tmp2[item.pos] = i; });
      store.forEach(function(item, i) { item._newPos = tmp2[i]; });
      grid.set("sort", "_newPos", descending);
    }
    else grid.set("sort", field, descending);
  
    grid.updateSortArrow([{property: field, descending: descending}]);
  
  }

  grid.on("dgrid-sort", function(e) {
    grid.doSort(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  // initial sort of the grid, use this instead of grid.set("sort"...)
  grid.doSort({sort: [{property: "field1", descending: false}]});

  grid.startup();
  
});
```

```html
<script>
dojoConfig = {
  async: true,
  packages: [
    {
      name: 'dgrid',
      location: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0'
    },
    {
      name: 'dstore',
      location: '//cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dstore/v1.1.1'
    }
  ]
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SitePen/dgrid/v1.1.0/css/dgrid.css" />

<body>
  <div id="grid" style="width:300px;height:530px;">
  </div>
</body>
```